# oracle sql developer tool - data not available after commit

Tags: sql, database, oracle, insert

Inserted data in the table. If I execute select query, I can see the data inserted. But once I execute commit, then execute select query on the same window, no record found.

It is looks strange. Don't know what is the issue.

Comment: Post the insert and other information that might help you.

Comment: This is not standard behaviour, so it must be something wacky in your environment.  Filters in SQL Developer, triggers on the table, other developers playing a practical joke on you ...

Comment: Please edit your post and add the CREATE TABLE statement.  I'm particularly curious about whether it's a temporary table...

Comment: yes Bob. you are right. it is temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. It is a **Global Temporary Table**, where the table is created as
**ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS**.